# static file not uploaded

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, static

I am using React inside Django app and facing issue of not loading static file

my settings.py is

```
    from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-00cag42gtk)0_9#kn_8c3d1y-u!et#kqpa3@(i^bo@j@z#1jn9'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'leads.apps.LeadsConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'frontend'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'leadmanager.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'leadmanager.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

and index.html is

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>zohaib ul hassan</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        {% load static %}
        <script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the file I want to load is inside the frontend app which has a folder following path static/frontend/main.js remember this path is after the frontend folder/app.beside frontend app I also have a app known as lead but it is not affecting the code i think so.
tree structure
[image]

Comment: Can you post the project structure (tree) as well?

Comment: tree structure is added sir

Comment: @zohaib_webdev your project structure seems to show that you have a folder named main.js that contains your file main.js - `frontend/static/frontend/main.js/main.js`?

Comment: Do you also have a folder inside main.js inside frontend folder as you shared in the project structure above?

Comment: Do this `<script src="{% static 'frontend/main.js/main.js' %}"></script>` note that you should give single quotes inside double quotes and the `main.js` file is also inside `main.js` folder as per the image you shared, kindly try it if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## -------- handle Static Files In django --------

```
# Steps:
    # 1 - Create (static) folder in Root Directory of Project
    # 2 - Paste Your Static Files Folder in (static) Folder (js,css,images...etc)
    # 3 - Now Do Setting in (setting.py)
           STATIC_URL = '/static/'

           import os
           STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
            # ---------- OR ------------------------
            # ---------- if Django version 3.2 ------------------------
           STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR /'static']



    # 4 - add {% load static %} tag on top of html page
    # 5 - Now use ({% static 'assets/image.jpg' %}) tag in HTML File for calling static files
    # 6 - Done
```

## =========== in html =============

```
<img src="{% static '1.png' %}" alt="" srcset="">
```

===== static folder path =============

[image]

## =========== output ===========

[image]

Comment: but sir i want to load from inside the app

Comment: yes above setting working with app > static 

please see answer updated